# How to make Transparent NavBar in AppShell Xamarin forms

Tags: shell, xamarin

[This is an example of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2H6f.jpg)

I am using a Xamarin Forms 4.5 with Shell. Most of my pages have an image for the background. How do I make the Navbar transparent so that I can scale my image over that space? I see that there are options to set the Navbar background color but that had no effect.

Comment: I test `BackgroundColor="Transparent"`, it is not worked in `Shell` as yours, but if I set the `BackgroundColor` to `Gray` or `Green`, it worked as normal. You can report this issue to github. https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues